# Append one array to another array with same key

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays

```
$array1 = array(33=>'abc,bcd,cde,def');
$array2 = array(33=>'fgh,ghi,hij,ijk');
```

How I can add two arrays to get the below result?

```
$array3 = array(33=>'abc,bcd,cde,def,fgh,ghi,hij,ijk');
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: `$arr3[33] = $arr1[33]. $arr2[33];`

Comment: Do both arrays _always_ contain the same set of keys?

Comment: Yes...Jack,Thanks,HappyApe it works..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you want to do this automatically for multiple keys. Try something like this:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
    $newArray[$key] = $array1[$key] . ',' . $array2[$key];
}
```

Keep in mind you will need checks to see if the data is in both arrays if they do not exactly match.